# Get request works in postman but not with python code - error 404

Tags: python, python-requests, postman

The request below is working in Postman but if I copy the code from Postman to `VS Code` or `PyCharm` I get always **HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.** I am running out of ideas, any help is appreciated. I am working behind a proxy but that is well sorted as far as I can see, since I had before the **407 error**, which is solved now. The localhost `api` is a `django api` I developed and I get it running from `PyCharm`.

import requests

```
url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/jobs/"
payload={}
files={}
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226166/discussion-on-question-by-milan-k-get-request-works-in-postman-but-not-with-pyth).

Comment: It worked, os.environ['NO_PROXY'] = '127.0.0.1' is the right answer. Thanks taskalman!

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import requests

os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = os.environ['http_proxy'] = 'http://http-connect-proxy:3128/'
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = os.environ['https_proxy'] = 'http://http-connect-proxy:3128/'
os.environ['NO_PROXY'] = os.environ['no_proxy'] = ''

url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/jobs/"
payload={}
files={}
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)
print(response.text)
```

Could you try replacing it with your proxy server and try

Comment: Still get HTTP Error 404 but thanks for trying.

Comment: I updated the code could you try replacing the http and https proxy with the one you have

Comment: Getting the following error now: Max retries exceeded with url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/jobs/ (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000000CC64A13CC0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'

Comment: but in the browser and Postman it's working just fine

Comment: Could you goto postman settings>proxy and see if proxy is enabled ? Also in browser check of proxy is enabled . Then check if localhost is set as not use proxy for localhost in system proxy settings

Comment: I think this answer is scratching things in the right place, but just does the opposite, compared to what I would do, that is: forces the use of the proxy instead of making sure, that the proxy is never hit for `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: the question mentions that proxy is used in browser and postman , so thats why the proxy none was left empty. That was the last comment was for if localhost should indeed be skipped local host can be added to the none part